# Cytoscape .js check when all nodes are unselected

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to achieve this:
when I `unselect` all the nodes on the graph I perform an operation.

The problem is that `unselect` event fires before the `select` event. In this way I can not check if I'm unselecting for a new node selection or I'm performing a click in the white space of the graph.

I tryed to check if there are other node still selected in the `unselect` event, but it is not possible because this event fires before `select` event.

Is there a way to achive that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It would be nice if you can share some code that depicts the issue

Comment: Thanks @Abhi, i resolved with the on click event

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since you didn't provide a code example but you can try listening to both select and unselect with a single function

```
cy.on('select unselect', (e) => {
  if (e.type == 'select') {
  
  } else {
    if (cy.$(':selected').length == 0){
      // do some action here. There are no selected elements
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: unluckily the problem it's the same, this method just assign the same function to both events but they are always executed in the same order ( unselect before select ).

Comment: I think. There is a different issue in your codes. Maybe you are firing `select` event by mistake. If you `unselect` an element, `select` event should not be triggered.